# error: unresolved reference: kotlinx aosp

Tags: kotlin, android-source, kotlin-coroutines

My App got built in Andriod studio without any issue when porting to AOSP I am getting the following error
error: unresolved reference: kotlinx import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

What plugin should I add to Andriod.bp to resolve this

Comment: post your code so we know the context

Answer (score 3):

Your error is due to missing `'kotlin-android-extensions'` plugin.
If you were building in Android Studio via gradle adding that would be the solution.

For AOSP I don't think that there is a support for applying Gradle plugins.

You have two options here:

1. Build you app via gradle as before, and in AOSP only inlcude the prebuilt apk.
2. Remove the usage of Kotlin android extensions in your code, and replace them with good old `findViewByID`